# Google analytics 0% bounce rate with redirect

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, analytics

I am working with an legacy site that uses a central page to do some setup before redirecting to the requested page. We are seeing a 0% bounce rate for all these requested pages because this central page is becoming the referrer (options.asp).

It looks like google event tracking has a 'no interaction' option.. but I can't find anything similar for the main tracking code.

For clarity, this is an example of a request path. The following URL forces product pages to load a product page with French locale and language set.

```
www.website.com/fr/products/product-name/
```

this resolves to:

```
www.website.com/options.asp
```

The language and locale are setup and the user is redirected to the final location:

```
www.website.com/product/product-name/
```

While I realise this is far from ideal, it is what it is. In this case it's more practical to keep the legacy site running while we redevelop the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, happy for it to be closed if it's the wrong place to ask. I assumed it was a question helpful to other web devs. Seems that google's documentation is limited on this and most search results focus on people having their google tag twice.. a solution to this will be helpful for others I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really phrase this as a question, so I'm assuming that you are seeking to get an accurate bounce rate so you can improve site performance.

Google defines "Bounce rate" as:
A bounce is a single-page session on your site. In Analytics, a bounce is calculated specifically as a session that triggers only a single request to the Analytics server, such as when a user opens a single page on your site and then exits without triggering any other requests to the Analytics server during that session.
Sauce: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en

If you do a redirect, your second page will never be a single page session.  Other analytics tools may only calculate bounce rate if the landing page is the first page of the site.
Sauce: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-some-of-my-pages-showing-0-bounce-rate

Recommended solution:
Since you are using ASP try using the server.transfer function.  What this will do is serve the page from the new URL without doing a redirect. Make sure that you use a canonical tag in your page header so Google knows what the correct url should be, and doesn't penalize you for having different content on the same URL.
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_transfer.asp

Canonical tags:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Hi David. That's a super helpful answer. For some, the transfer method might be perfect. Using it in this case won't change the URL.. the user will land on options.asp and stay there. I need to to end up on /product/url.

Comment: Everything about the solution is working except that google doesn't allow me to say that the hit on options.asp is to be discounted.

Comment: Then use a 301 permanent redirect and put the canonical tag in your page.  Search traffic will be sent directly to the page, so you'll get accurate bounce rates for those pages.  For customers coming in through the first page, your bounce rate will remain broken. You can't have mandatory redirect every time and working bounce rate.